# Mapbox - Do map tiles get unloaded?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

When zooming into the map, do the tiles ever get unloaded? Or do they just stack on top of each other? For example - if I zoom in from zoom level 4 to zoom level 6, do the new set of tiles replace the old ones? Or do they simply cover them?

The reason I am asking is that I am loading a 3D terrain mesh on top of each tile that loads, but I have found that I am getting multiple terrains stacking on top of each other (refer to my aforementioned zoom level example).

Ideally I would like to simply unload the terrain cover whenever the corresponding tile unloads, but the mapbox-gl library does not seem to expose that event...

Any info on this subject would help me figure out a working solution. Thanks!

Comment: Are you planning to share your 3D terrain in Mapbox GL code? It would be awesome to see that.

Comment: Sure thing! It is very [similar to this example](https://blog.mapbox.com/bringing-3d-terrain-to-the-browser-with-three-js-410068138357) however it does not recreate the entire mapping library (wihch the example does) to generate the terrain. Instead, I am relying on mapbox-gl to do all the heavy lifting. Right now its only a few hundred lines of code and it works! (but not well).